# How to apply a continious substitution reduction of (-1 + 3 phi - 2 phi^3 - 6 phi^4 - 20 phi^6 + 6 phi^7 + 3 phi^8 + phi^9)//.{phi^3->1-phi^2}

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have the answer to

```
(-1 + 3 phi - 2 phi^3 - 6 phi^4 - 20 phi^6 + 6 phi^7 + 3 phi^8 + phi^9)/.{phi^3->1- 
phi^2}
```

that is not the problem.  I am looking for a method that continues to apply this reduction until there are only linear and quadratic terms involving phi in one step.  I have a lot of these reductions and some are a lot more complicated.

I have to apply this substitution, expand, then apply again for each reduction in powers of phi until I have no more than quadratic terms.  So for example the phi^9 powers is eliminated by `/.{phi^9->(1-phi^2)^3}`, expand and continue.

Comment: `ReplaceRepeated` (aka `//.`) will do this

Comment: `PolynomialReduce[` is quite good for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expr /. {ToRules[
   Reduce[{(-1 + 3 phi - 2 phi^3 - 6 phi^4 - 20 phi^6 + 6 phi^7 + 
        3 phi^8 + phi^9) == expr, phi^3 == 1 - phi^2}, expr]]}
```

> {1 - 24 phi + 23 phi^2, 1 - 24 phi + 23 phi^2, 1 - 24 phi + 23 phi^2}

`Reduce` is used to find the simplest possible form for the `expr` under the given condition (`phi^3 == 1 - phi^2`), and `expr /. {ToRules[...]}` is used to isolate the expression of interest from `Reduce`'s result.

Note that this returns a list of results: any result here should be a valid form of the expression under some condition. In this case, they're all the same, but they may not always be. You can grab one with `First` or you can keep them all (or use `DeleteDuplicates` or so on).

Answer (score 3):

Several methods can be used. The simplest use only polynomial operations. The code

```
p = -1 + 3 phi - 2 phi^3 - 6 phi^4 - 20 phi^6 + 6 phi^7 + 3 phi^8 + phi^9;
q = phi^3 - 1 + phi^2;  r = 1 - 24*phi + 23*phi^2;   (* r is the result *)
{r == PolynomialReduce[p, q, phi][[2]], r == PolynomialRemainder[p, q, phi]}
```

returns `{True, True}`.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Simplify[-1+3 phi-2 phi^3-6 phi^4-20 phi^6+6 phi^7+3 phi^8+phi^9, phi^3 == 1-phi^2]
```

gives this

```
(*1 - 24*phi + 23*phi^2*)
```